# Need help changing the Index Page description text font-size so that I can use it as a header & as a sub-header?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

Disclaimer: I'm brand new to coding

I said I'd help a friend that needed to set up a quick site. I decided to just use squarespace since I thought it'd be the easiest.

I encountered a problem. I'm using the Tremont Template and using the Index page landing page.

It uses the Index page description and displays it as a header. I wanted to use that same text but split it so that I had a header & sub-header. I've tried injecting the code into the site for about 5 hours now and have gotten nowhere.

I need to change the code from:

```
<div id="collectionDesc" class="collection-desc">
    <p><strong>
       TE LLEVAMOS AL NUEVO MUNDO DE LUZ.
    </strong></p>
    <p>La luz LED es nuestra pasión. Entendemos si no es la tuya, 
    o si no cuentas con el conocimiento de como mejor implementarla, 
    o si prefieres dedicar tus recursos a otras prioridades en tu organización.</p>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="collectionDesc" class="collection-desc">
    <p><strong style="font-size: 60px; line-height: normal; ">
       TE LLEVAMOS AL NUEVO MUNDO DE LUZ.</strong></p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">
       La luz LED es nuestra pasión. Entendemos si no es la tuya, 
       o si no cuentas con el conocimiento de como mejor implementarla, 
       o si prefieres dedicar tus recursos a otras prioridades en tu 
       organización.</p>
</div>
```

The collection id is: collection-587186ed86e6c094c88fe8e1

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm desperate for help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make styles in just one line.

```html
<div id="collectionDesc" class="collection-desc">
  <p><strong style="font-size: 60px; line-height: normal;">TE LLEVAMOS AL NUEVO MUNDO DE LUZ.</strong>
  </p>
  <p style="font-size: 20px;">La luz LED es nuestra pasión. Entendemos si no es la tuya, o si no cuentas con el conocimiento de como mejor implementarla, o si prefieres dedicar tus recursos a otras prioridades en tu organización.</p>
</div>
```

Or even better add a CSS file:

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

#collectionDesc p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="collectionDesc" class="collection-desc">
  <h3>TE LLEVAMOS AL NUEVO MUNDO DE LUZ.
  </h3>
  <p>La luz LED es nuestra pasión. Entendemos si no es la tuya, o si no cuentas con el conocimiento de como mejor implementarla, o si prefieres dedicar tus recursos a otras prioridades en tu organización.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I tried both and unfortunately neither changed the text other than pushing it down a little further.

Comment: Hmm, could you give me the URL to your site?